# github page font and index.html not working

Tags: html, css, font-face, github-pages

i created a repo on github fr my blog alireza.one and now i want to create a Persian blog and i have two problems:

First: font face doesn't load. i put an import line on my css but it doesn't load.

```
@import url('https://alireza.one/farsi/assets/type.css');
```

My Farsi (Persian) blog loads my main css but the font isn't loaded. My repository: [alirezahy/farsi](https://github.com/alirezahy/farsi). My webpage: [alireza.one/farsi](https://alireza.one/farsi)

Second: My index.html (both in Farsi repo and alirezahy.github.io) is like this:

```
---
layout: default
title: Index
---


<div class="listing">
    {% for post in paginator.posts %}
    <div class="post other link">
      <h2></span> <a href="{{site.url}}{{post.url}}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
      <p class="post-date">{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

How can i make it to a normal index.html so my front page appears like a normal weblog not as a site page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a font, you would need to add it like this in your css file:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "myFont";
src: url(fontofallknowledge.woff);
}
```

And then you can use the font by using it like this

```
body{
font-family: "myFont";
}
```

You would use the @import to import stylesheets.

To answer your second question, you seem to be using php in your .html file. You cannot do this.